# Make JWindow retain focus when children are focused, including another window as child

Tags: java, swing, focus, jwindow

I have created `JWindow`, which has several `JTextInput` fields. This `JWindow` parent is `JFrame`. Now the situation - if text fields are clicked - they get the focus BUT `JWindow` also stays focused. That is good. But if I create another `JWindow` (child of first `JWindow`), and set it visible, then focus on first `JWindow` is lost, and the child `JWindow` is focused. This is bad. Is there some way to retain focus on the parent `JWindow`, and to make the child `JWindow` get the focus like `JTextInput` fields?

Answer (score 4):

JWindow without parent never will be focusable, carefully then JTextComponents never will be editable

for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class WindowTest {

    private JFrame frame;
    private boolean bol = true;

    public WindowTest() {
        frame = new JFrame("Window Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JWindow win = new JWindow(frame);
        win.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        JTextField text = new JTextField("Show Window");
        text.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                if (!bol) {
                    JWindow win = new JWindow();
                    win.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
                    win.add(new JTextField("JTextField"));
                    win.add(new JTextField("JTextField"));
                    win.add(new JLabel("<html> Concurency Issues in Swing<br>"
                            + " never to use Thread.sleep(int) <br>"
                            + " durring EDT, simple to freeze GUI </html>"));
                    win.pack();
                    win.setLocation(350, 150);
                    win.setVisible(true);
                    bol = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
        });
        win.add(text);
        win.add(new JTextField("JTextField"));
        win.add(new JTextField("JTextField"));
        win.pack();
        win.setLocation(250, 150);
        win.setVisible(true);

        bol = false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new WindowTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice example, didn't know it before. Actually I have solved the problem by restricting to change the color (to inactive) of my custom title bar of parent `JWindow` if child `JWindow` gains the focus. Thanks again indeed :)

Comment: Also I had to play with `WindowFocusListener` and `FocusListener` after I have read these lines "As of this release, showing a JPopupMenu causes focus to transfer to the parent JRootPane. This was done so that JPopupMenus would support keyboard traversal..." from [here](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/swing/1.4/SwingChanges.html). I thought before that JWindow have some setting to behave like for example JTextField when it gains focus (parent JWindow retains window focus).

Comment: because from Java1.4 isn't possible to stay visible without Focus, loose Fosus hide JPopup or BasicComboBoxPopup

Answer (score 2):

Before setting the child window visible, add a `WindowListener`.  After you call `setVisible` on the child window, you'll receive the `windowActivated` callback.  At that point call `toFront` on your parent window to bring it forward.  Given the quirkiness of OS z-order handling, you might need/want to call `toBack` on the child window first, as well as calling `requestFocus` on the parent window or one of its focusable children afterward.