# Java JTextPane not receiving keystrokes

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, mouseevent, jtextpane

I have in the little bit of code below a `JWindow` with a `JTextPane` in it. When I run the full code in Netbeans it creates a nice window, but the `JTextPane` won't respond to mouse or keyboard events. When I mouse over it, the text mouse icon appears, but when I click on it, it selects the Netbeans window behind it. I've tried to call the `setFocusable` method of the `JTextPane` with `true` and called `grabFocus` as well.. How can I get the `JTextPane` to respond to mouse and keyboard events?

I have two files. One is called `MainClass.java` and just creates a new `MainWindow` object. `MainWindow.java` is where the problem is. It has a artificial title bar, two sides, and the centered `JTextPanel` that is giving me problems.

Please note that using a `JFrame` is not an option.

Thanks!

### MainWindow.java

```
package Window;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;

public class MainWindow extends JWindow{
    private Color TitleColor = new Color(18, 15, 65);
    private Color BGColor = new Color(50, 50, 50);

    public MainWindow(){
        GraphicsEnvironment env =
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        Rectangle MaxBounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();

        SpringLayout Layout = new SpringLayout();
        Container ContentPane = this.getContentPane();
        this.setLayout(Layout);

        JPanel TitleBar = new JPanel();
        TitleBar.setBackground(TitleColor);
        TitleBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 30));
        this.add(TitleBar);

        JPanel LeftPanel = new JPanel();
        LeftPanel.setBackground(BGColor);
        this.add(LeftPanel);

        JPanel RightPanel = new JPanel();
        RightPanel.setBackground(BGColor);
        this.add(RightPanel);

        JTextPane TextPane = new JTextPane();
        TextPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        TextPane.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        TextPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 0));
        TextPane.setFocusable(true);
        TextPane.setMargin(new Insets(20,20,20,20));
        TextPane.grabFocus();
        this.add(TextPane);

        Layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, TitleBar, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, ContentPane);
        Layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, TitleBar, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, ContentPane);
        Layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, TitleBar, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, ContentPane);

        Layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, TextPane, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, TitleBar);
        Layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, TextPane, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, ContentPane);
        Layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.HORIZONTAL_CENTER, TextPane, 0, SpringLayout.HORIZONTAL_CENTER, ContentPane);

        Layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, LeftPanel, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, TitleBar);
        Layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, LeftPanel, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, ContentPane);
        Layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, LeftPanel, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, TextPane);
        Layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, LeftPanel, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, ContentPane);

        Layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, RightPanel, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, TitleBar);
        Layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, RightPanel, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, ContentPane);
        Layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, RightPanel, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, ContentPane);
        Layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, RightPanel, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, TextPane);

        this.setBounds(MaxBounds);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

### MainClass.java

```
package Window;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
              new MainWindow();  
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: From the [documentation of `isFocusableWindow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isFocusableWindow%28%29): “For a Window which is not a Frame or Dialog to be focusable, its focusable Window state must be set to true, its nearest owning Frame or Dialog must be showing on the screen, and it must contain at least one Component in its focus traversal cycle. If any of these conditions is not met, then neither this Window nor any of its subcomponents can become the focus owner.”

Comment: Thank you! That doc was very informative. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `JTextComponents` placed in `JWindow` without parent isn't editable etc.
- you would need to set [`JFrame (never need to be visible)` as parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18282417/714968), then everything works

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll be sure to test that.

Comment: @trashgod ... camicrks down_vote wrote this info into my head